How can I make the density portion of the "Pre_Admit_PES_Annual_Rate" more prominent?
I have a data set; I'd like to display the differences between two Annual Rates  (Pre vs Post) and am making raincloud plots for each. I am somewhat satisfied by the boxplot/scatter but would like to make the density portion more prominent.
ggplot(data, aes(x = Variable_day, y = Value_day, fill = Variable_day)) + 
     ggdist::stat_halfeye(
         adjust = 5, 
         width = .6, 
         .width = 0, 
         justification = -.2, 
         point_colour = NA
     ) + 
     geom_boxplot(
         width = .15, 
         outlier.shape = NA
     ) +
     gghalves::geom_half_point(
         side = "l", 
         range_scale = .4, 
         alpha = .2
     ) +
     coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.2, 2.9), ylim = c(0,25), clip = "off")


data set (csv): https://pastebin.com/f2kvgtQ0

Please provide your data using dput(data) so others can help. See [MRE] for guidance.
